# How to ignore extra parameters in URL?

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, location

< noob >
This following code works like a charm when I use the proper URL

*www.exemple.com/?login*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function urlparam(){
    var url = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
    if (url == 'login' ) {
        document.getElementById('loginMainContainer').style.display = 'block';
        $('.login').triggerHandler('click');
    } else if (url == 'signup' ){
            document.getElementById('loginMainContainer').style.display = 'block';
            $('.signup').triggerHandler('click');
    }
}
    urlparam()   
});
```

But once I need to use this URL with other parameters (w/ mailchimp)

*www.exemple.com/?login&utm_source=App+Accounts&utm_campaign=e94f95d4da-News_promo+email_English_2016*

It really doesn't execute what I need.
Is there a way to ignore these extra parameters and execute properly my function?

Thanks for any help in advanced!

< /noob >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regular expression to handle this, it tests to match if the string starts with login or if it starts with signup.

```
    var url = ('www.exemple.com/?login&utm_source=App+Accounts&utm_campaign=e94f95d4da-News_promo+email_English_2016').toString().split('?')[1];
    if (url.match(/^login/ )) {
        console.log('login');
    } else if (url.match(/^signup/ )){
        console.log('signup');
    }
```

Comment: Lovely! Thank a lot. I just changed the first line to:

`var url = window.location.toString().split('?')[1];`

Comment: Sure no problem glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to get all parameter and check if `login` exist.

```js
var url="http://someurl.com?test=ok&machin=1234&login&azir=lol";

function parameterExist(url,paramName)
{
  var parameters = url.split('?')[1].split('&');
  for(var i=0;i<parameters.length;i++)
  {
     var paramNameUrl=parameters[i].split('=')[0];
     if(paramNameUrl==paramName)
       return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(parameterExist(url,"login"));
console.log(parameterExist(url,"blabla"));
```